# Tipo de dato en SQL Server C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla con una columna llamada consecutivo con el tipo de dato  **char(20)**,
en mi aplicación en **c#** llamo esta columna pero al poner el tipo de dato en el código en la web me sale **conversión especificada no es válida.**  lo mismo pasa con el **datetime**, he intentado varias opciones pero no logro hacerlo alguna ayuda?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que Char(20) debería ser un STRING en c# y la fecha un datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualiza tu campo a valor string y ponle datetime al valor de fecha, espero resuelva tu error

```
    consecutivo = (String)x["consecutivo"]
    codvendedor = (String)x["codvendedor"]
    codtipodcto = (String)x["codtipodcto"]
    Fecha = (Datetime)x["Fecha"]
```

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente por que tu respuesta es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Comment: Ya lo edite, podrias actualiar tu voto?